# Regex - capture words after match

Tags: python, regex

I have a string where I am trying to match word patterns which appear either directly after, or one word after a tag. For example:

```
after_tag = r'here is sentence as an example where a [TAG] ~~M001~~ a word'
one_after_tag = r'here is sentence as an example where a [TAG] can ~~M001~~ a word'
```

I would also like to extend this to work with connecting words, there have also been tagged. This should also work within a window a one or two words after the [CONNECT] tag, such as:

```
after_connect = r'here is a sentence where a [TAG] could [CONNECT] ~~M002~~'
one_after_connect = r'here is a sentence where a [TAG] could [CONNECT] a ~~M002~~'
```

I have tried the following regex with the re package in Python.

```
regex_current = re.compile(((?:(?<=(\{TAG})))(.*?)\~\~[A-Z0-9]{4,5}\~\~))
```

Please can anyone help? I've found the following [website](https://regex101.com/) helpful in testing.

Comment: Will your match contain `~`, letters, and numbers only? Will your TAG always contain `[]`?

Comment: Without using any lookbehind you can use such -> ```.+\[.+\].+\~\~(.+)\~\~``` , example -> https://regex101.com/r/PBFbC7/1

Comment: Yes, the matching term will always be enclosed by ~~. The tag will always be enclosed by []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution that matches both `~~...~~` words:

```
(?<=\[TAG\])( \w*)? ~~\w*~~
```

1. Look for `[TAG]` before match.
2. Match one or less words with no `~`
3. Match th `~` word.

If there is a word in between it will be matched as well, so you can either group the second word or split the result and use the last index.

[Here is the example](https://regex101.com/r/IFqVeO/1).

To encompass also the `CONNECT` examples just `or` the same thing:

```
(?<=\[TAG\])( \w*)? ~~\w*~~|(?<=\[CONNECT\])( \w*)? ~~\w*~~
```

It's the exact the regular expression, but the look-behind needs constant width. If you do not mind matching the TAG you can shorten this to:

```
\[(TAG|CONNECT)\]( \w*)? ~~\w*~~
```

This is really only needed if you expect there to be more `~~LettersAndDigits~~` words. If not, you can search for that exactly

```
~~\w*~~
```

without anything fancy.

**Final addition**

Two ensure both `TAG` and `CONNECT` appear (CONNECT optionally):

```
\[TAG\]( \w*)?( \[CONNECT\]( \w*)?)? ~~[\w]*~~
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/m3epzb/1). To only get the word in this case I would definitly using grouping `()`, as the match length is variable.

Comment: Thank you! This works for the top two examples nicely! Could this be extended for the connecting words?

Comment: @avocet Switch `TAG` with `CONNECT` and will be the same thing wouldn't it? You do not even need the TAG for these examples?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's really helped my understanding - appreciated. Understand what you mean, but there must be a TAG before a connect given it's use purpose. The TAG has a contextual meaning which is important. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: @avocet I added something that forces an optional match. Consider making sure something simpler may not be sufficient.

Comment: Works! Thank you!!